# NPM Dependency - Folder within a Git Repo?

Tags: node.js, git, npm, node-modules

Does NPM support installing dependencies via a Git URL to a sub-folder within the repo? I checked the documentation and it didn't look like there was a way, but I couldn't explicitly tell.

I know it does and I know how to setup a Git repo itself to serve as a dependency, something like this:

- (other files)
- package.json

But what I would like to do is basically use a monorepo pattern (like Babel), so I'd have a folder structure similar to this:

- packages/

  - packageA/

    - package.json
  - packageB/

    - package.json
  - packageC/

    - package.json

And then be able to install them all from the same repo just referring to `packageA`, `packageB` and `packageC`.

I know an alternative would be to have them all be part of one module, and then import them like `package/packageA`, but some of them aren't super related conceptually so that is less than ideal. The only reason they are in the same repo because I don't want NPM module repos clustering up our repository.

I know this is normally done with a private NPM repository, but we currently don't have access to one, so hoping there is an alternative.

Any ideas?

Comment: You cant' have multiples files with the same name. You'll be able to only one `packages/package.json`

Comment: Sorry, that was a goof in formatting. The package.json is nested under packageA, B, C. I'll fix it.

Comment: `npm` will install dependencies in `node_modules`. You can define sub-folders in `node_modules` but not install dependencies in different folders. Maybe you want to use [git submodules](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules) instead

Comment: Not quite. I basically want multiple Node modules per Git repo (without a private repository). Using Git submodules would be multiple Git repos per Node module.

Comment: AFAIK it's still a _"No"_. This feature was requested in [issue #2974](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/2974) a few years ago. The npm  [docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install) state you can target either; a `#<commit-ish>` (i.e. specific git commit), or a  `<semver>` (i.e. specific git tag) - unfortunately targeting sub-folder(s) within a git repo is not mentioned. However, in [issue #4725](https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/4725) for `yarn` the [gitpkg](https://github.com/ramasilveyra/gitpkg) package is mentioned that also works with npm - I haven't used it myself, maybe worth a try.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I'll check it out.

Comment: Where you able to find the solution?

Comment: The answer is basically "it doesn't" and I had to split it into multiple Git repos, unfortunately.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like https://gitpkg.now.sh/ is potentially what you want

Looking at the link that it produces it seems that it is acting as a proxy for your package in some way, so I wouldn't use this in mission critical production code but it should be fine if you're trying to test that something works between repos

Comment: Thanks for sharing, I'll have to check that out.